# VBA Code Analysis Tools

Tags: vba

Are there any good code analysis tools for VBA code?  I currently utilize [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx), which is quite good at what it does, but am looking for better analysis.

Comment: Note, while closed as "opinion based", it's not just because of the word "better".   This question is specifically off topic, due to this clause in the "don't ask" section: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

I've not used any of these myself, but they appear to be what you are looking for:

http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/VBACodingTools.html

FMS's president, Luke Chung, is a (former?) Microsoft MVP and is generally well-regarded.

Answer (score 3):

I used to quite like Aivosto's tools ; http://www.aivosto.com/

They are quite expensive, but also very thorough.